# Playing with numbers length

Tags: java, android, textview

In my recycerview's textview I have numbers like 2557.1564987892, 0.0015468648, 26.2648597816.
so I want if there is 4 numbers before the dot display only 2 numbers after the dot.
if there is 1 number before the dot display 5 numbers after the dot.
if there is 2 numbers before the dot display 4 numbers after the dot. 
which way they all have 6 total length.
Thank you.

Comment: There are different ways to achieve the same. The implementation way depends on: in which format will you use these values? As strings, or as floats/doubles? Perhaps both types? In both type values, there's a way to implement a solution.

Comment: I won't do any operation with the values, just for displaying values coming from api. I can define it in my model class neither String nor floats/doubles for a solution.

Comment: You do not seem to take in account the possibility of numbers with negative sign. Keep that in mind if necessary.

Comment: All the numbers are greater than 0. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
private static String fmtFixed(float value, int digits) {
    StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder("0.");
    float v = value;
    while (v >= 1) {
        digits--;
        v /= 10;
    }
    if (value < 1) {
        digits--;
    }
    while (digits > 0) {
        digits--;
        pattern.append("0");
    }
    return new DecimalFormat(pattern.toString()).format(value);
}
```

To use, you would call it like:

```
textView.setText(fmtFixed(2557.1564987892, 6));
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way in string format would be:

```
String truncateNumber(String input_num) {
    output = input_num.substring(0, 7);
    return output;
}

// Function usage
truncated_number = truncateNumber(any_number_as_string);
```

Substring method returns a substring from the original string, giving start and end positions.

Comment: This works, but will not round off the last digit, just truncate. It might be good enough for user, but rounding off is probably better, but will need more work.